# What is the best way to present or visualize the framework of my programming project

Tags: oop, visualization, software-design, diagram

I am a Civil Engineering student and I have been building add-in programs for Autodesk Revit using the Revit API which is written in C#. My Visual Studio Project is organized into classes that I have created for my program. What is the best/proper way to visualize and present/explain the overall framework/structure/architecture of my program? I want to explain how my code is structured along with their functionalities and interaction between classes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a diagram to show the high level modules/components of your system. Popular diagramming tools are [Microsoft Visio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/visio/flowchart-software/), [Modelio](https://www.modelio.org/) or [draw.io](https://app.diagrams.net/).

[UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) is a good option for structuring your diagrams. Use Sequence diagrams to describe time based interaction between objects/classes.

UML is a heavy modelling language so don't worry about using every kind of UML notation of in your diagram. Rather aim for clarity, less is more definitely applies here.

The Visual Studio Class Designer lets you create Class Diagrams of your software
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2019

In Visual Studio Enterprise Edition you can also add [code maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2017) if you have access to it.